# Datatables - where with two conditions

Tags: mysql, datatable, codeigniter-3

I used the following statement to filter records by subject ids. (Here subject_id=5)

```
$this->datatables->where('letter_letter.subject_id', 5);
```

That is working perfectly. Further I want to filter records in subject_id range like 1 to 10. Then I  changed my code as follows :

```
$this->datatables->where('letter_letter.subject', 10, '<');
```

But did not get the desired output. How can I edit my code to get expected result ? Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two calls to `where()` to define the range:

```
$this->datatables->where('letter_letter.subject_id >= ', 1);
$this->datatables->where('letter_letter.subject_id <=', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can make a `where` query with two conditions:

```
$this->datatables->where("letter_letter.subject_id IS ? AND letter_letter.subject BETWEEN ? AND ?", 5, 1, 10)
```